# Dúvida sobre tags parecidas

Tags: debate, tags, tag-específica

Na seguinte [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178424/erro-em-uso-de-action-ass%C3%ADncrona-async) tem as tags `asp.net`, `asp.net-mvc` e `asp.net-mvc5`

Isso é uma espécie de generalização/especialização, pois `asp.net-mvc5` está dentro `asp.net-mvc`, e `asp.net-mvc` está dentro de `asp.net`. São quase sinônimos, mas as primeiras são mais específicas.

Está correto usar todas, ou o certo é deixar apenas a mais específica que é `asp.net-mvc-5`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em geral usar [asp.net-mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) e [asp.net-mvc-5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-5) é correto, porque uma indica para quem segue o assunto que tem pergunta nova e outra dá uma contexto maior.

Na verdade é comum ser um erro usar a versão porque a pergunta não tem nada específico da versão 5, então ele está até passando uma informação errada e pode ter uma solução que não é ma mais adequada para ele. Ele está usando a 5 por acaso, o problema nada tem a ver com ela, é com a tecnologia de forma geral. Na maioria das vezes não vai causar problemas, mas pode acontecer de alguém dar uma solução que não é a mais adequada. É um erro semelhante quando a pessoa usa [visual-studio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio), ele está usando o VS para fazer sua aplicação, mas para aquele problema é irrelevante, o problema não é no Visual Studio.

Colocar [asp.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) junto com [asp.net-mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) costuma ser um erro. Pode não ser, pode ter uma relação, mas quase sempre é errado porque são tecnologias completamente diferentes uma da outra. Colocar essa *tag* pode produzir respostas erradas e em uma pesquisa vai incluir essa pergunta que nada tem a ver com ASP.NET.

Outro erro comum é colocar [mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc). A não ser que a pergunta seja sobre o padrão de arquitetura MVC em geral e não a tecnologia é um erro. Na verdade usam junto com [asp.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) quando na verdade queriam usar [asp.net-mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc).

Mas o pior erro é usar [asp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp) que é outra tecnologia bem diferente, bem incompatível e obsoleta. Costuma ser usando junto com [.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) é é outra *tag* de outra coisa. É comum usarmos ela porque .NET é uma tecnologia que engloba várias tecnologias. Podemos dizer que [.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) é uma *tag* hierárquica. porque tudo isso é sobre .NET e quem quer saber algo dele vai achar fácil com ela. Mas ela deve ser usada por si próprio, não pode ser usada junto com [asp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp) quando na verdade queria usar [asp.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net).

Então não tem 2 especializações, só tem 1, e ela é útil em alguns casos. Acho um enorme erro na maioria dos casos, e mais errado ainda ter só a *tag* com versão e não ter a geral. Prejudica principalmente buscas.

Comment: Tem também o caso de [tag:asp.net-mvc-4], que acho que ajuda a entender como essas tags funcionam.

Comment: Estou editando algumas questões com as tags 'mvc' e 'asp.net' quando devia ser apenas 'asp.net-mvc'

Comment: @Murilo ótimo. Só evite mudar várias ao mesmo tempo em horário de grande movimento para não monopolizar a página inicial, já que cada alteração coloca a pergunta lá.

Comment: Beleza. Entendido.Qual é o melhor horário para edições em massa?

Comment: @Murilo madrugada :D à noite não é tão ruim, FDS tb costuma sr + tranquilo. Pode fazer em qualquer horário, mas aí faz devagarzinho, não deixa encavalar vários seguidos.